# How to translate old OneNote Links so they work with OneNote 2013

Tags: microsoft-onenote, links

I have many OneNote links in OneNote pages as well as from external documents such as mindmap files to pages in OneNote 2007.  I recently converted my notebooks to the latest oneNote format so I can share in the cloud but now all of my old links do not work.  Is there a any way to (1) convert the old links, or if that is not possible, (2) at least find out what the old links point to?